# reading json data from a file

Tags: javascript, json, go

I am running a server with Go programming language, and when I load the server in the browser, the temp handler function is called and the getjson.html file is served by this temp Handler function. Now the screen shows a "Get Json Data" button. On clicking this button, I am not getting any results (as something should be displayed on the screen).

I checked the javascript console and there are no errors as such. 
I am not able to figure out what the problem is, why isn't there any output on the screen.

Contents of servejson.go :

```
package main

import (
    "http"
    "flag"
)

var path = flag.String("root", "/home/chinmay/work/json/getjson.html", "Set root directory, use absolute path")

func temp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    http.ServeFile(w,r,*path)
}

func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/",temp)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Contents of getjson.html :

```
package main

import (
    "http"
    "flag"
)

var path = flag.String("root", "/home/chinmay/work/json/getjson.html", "Set root directory, use absolute path")

func temp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    http.ServeFile(w,r,*path)
}

func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/",temp)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Contents of json_data.js:

```
{ 
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 25
}
```

Comment: Yes, that should be possible - `getJSON()` *should* do this even though the text file's content type will be `text/plain`. I'm not entirely sure, but  why not simply try out?

Comment: Are you trying to read the text file from the local machine? I don't believe that is possible in js

Comment: actually i am running a server and then i would serve this html file containing the js script which would then try to access the file.txt to get the json data and print it to the screen.

Comment: @chinmay: That's fine, provided `json.txt` is available via HTTP and (with the path you've given) is a peer of the document in which this code is running (e.g., `http://example.com/page.html` and `http://example.com/json.txt`).

Comment: Could you just tell me why my code I have given above isn't running, it follows what you have said ! However I am not able to get any output as you showed me in your example. You're not accessing a file and I am trying to access a file json.txt, could you show you example in this perspective ?

Comment: @chinmay: PLEASE refer to the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the question area, to the **[?]** above the question area, and to the preview below it. I've already fixed your formatting once, and your latest edit breaks it again. Also, your edit makes no sense, what you're (now) showing for "Contents of getjson.html" looks exactly like the contents of "servejson.go". I was going to fix the code formatting for you again, but got thrown by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. [Live example.](http://jsbin.com/alateh) Provided that `json.txt` is a resource next to the document in which this code is running, and (on some browsers) provided this is not running from a local file (e.g., a `file://` URL rather than an `http://` one; some browsers are okay with local files accessing other local files via ajax, others are not).

A couple of notes:

- In the

  ```
  $("div").append(field + " ");
  ```

  line, `field` will be the *value* of each property (e.g., "John").
- The order in which the properties are listed is completely undefined.

So for this *specific* example, you'd probably be better off with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("json.txt",function(result){
      $("div").append(result.firstName + " " + result.lastName + " " + result.age);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/alateh/2)

---

**Update**: From your comments on another answer, it seems like you might be unclear on where and how the script code is running. The JavaScript script runs on the client's browser. The path to use to reference `json.txt` is exactly like (say) the path to an image you want to show on a page. `json.txt` must be accessible via the web server, just like an image would need to be accessible via the web server. Think of `json.txt` as just another resource used by your web page, like any other. In terms of the path, and how you have to make `json.txt` available, the same rules apply. To be clear: Script running client-side in a web page cannot access a server-side file that can't be retrieved by the browser.

---

**Update 2**: You've posted more code, and it looks like you've made your server *only* serve the `getjson.html` file. Your server *also* has to serve the `json.txt` file, or the browser can't access it.

Comment: Please checkout the example http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_getjson

Comment: @chinmay: That's basically what I did with the live links. I'm not seeing why you wanted to look at it...?

Comment: I wanted to look at it because the code is handling file "demo_ajax_json.js" in the .html part, this is exactly what I would like to do. I am trying to do it using a go server whose code I have given above. It basically serves the .html file, this .html file then tries to do what is done in the example. However, I am not able to get the expected outputs. Where am I wrong in here ? 
Are the paths of the files correct in the code ? The .html file is getting served but when I press the getJSONdata button nothing happens, nothing gets printed :(

Comment: @chinmay: I've discussed the paths and what's required above.

Comment: I have followed exactly what you're saying. Please checkout my code above I have edited the question. I seriously need some guidance regarding why the code isn't working i.e. when I press the getjsonbutton (of .html file), I get no output. I have been stuck here for hours. Please I need your Help. Help..

Comment: @chinmay: **Again:** The `json.txt` file must be accessible **FROM THE BROWSER**. Type in the URL of the `json.txt` file in your browser window. Do you see the JSON? If not, then it's not accessible to the browser. Once it is, your client-side code using it will work. I don't know the server technology you're using enough to understand what that server code will and won't serve, but you just need to make sure `json.txt` is in the right place to served, and that the server is configured to serve it.

Comment: I type file:///home/chinmay/work/json/json_data.js in the browser and I get the contents of the json_data.js file (contains json data). It means json_data.js is accessible by the browser. However, still my browser code isn't working. I don't get what is wrong ?

Comment: @chinmay: You can't reliably use Ajax with `file://` URLs, just HTTP(S) ones. Some browsers allow `file://` URLs to load other `file://` URLs via ajax, but most don't. And you certainly can't load a `file://` URL from an `http://` URL for obvious security reasons. Your `json.txt` (or `json_data.js`, you seem to have changed the name?) and your `getjson.html` files must both be accessed via HTTP, which is why I keep banging on about your needing to *serve* the JSON file.

Comment: sorry for so much trouble, finally got what you're saying. Thank you very much!

Comment: @chinmay: No worries, hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this isn't related to Go, but I falt here while searching a solution to a similar problem in JQuery and the solution isn't related to the tool used.

I got a problem today to simulate a Json query on a program linked to a database, without the database. So I saved a Json result to a file and wanted to use it instead. The json.txt file was on a server and viewable in the browser but $.getJSON was trowing an error.

To solve this problem, all I had to do is to **rename the file with an "html" extention**, like json.html and to remove the header in the file. i.e. You need to NOT have "Content-Type: application/json" in the begining of your text file.

Could be specific to a web server (Apache) or browser security (Firefox) but at least it worked.

Answer (score -1):

$.getJSON() needs a URL as a parameter.  You are trying to access a file from the directory structure of the local machine/server which is not possible in JS.

See the jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/